# Issue with wordpress new page creation

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This might be a simple question. I can't seem to figure out the right question to ask to google. Every time I create a new page on my WordPress site. I get this from the default theme. I am using a different header footer then this. But I can't find where to delete this image and min nav from. if someone can point me in the right direction or explain where to look to disable this it would be very helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrrgh! Stock images of hipsters! Make them go away!

This is called a header image.

From your dashboard go to Appearance > Customize. There will, probably, be an item on the left called "Header". In there is, probably, a user interface allowing you to upload a different header image or delete it entirely.

Comment: Hey Jones! 
Thank you very much for your joke and guidance. I found what I was looking for close to where you suggested. 

Appearance > Customize > Page Title > Hide Page Title